# Protected member not recognized in eclipse C++

Tags: c++, eclipse, inheritance, protected

I have the following classes where I try to acces a protected member of the Base class but I get an error in eclipse "Field Factorized could not be resolved". Can someone explain to me what am I doing wrong? Why can't I access to the variable `mFactorized` ??

**BASE CLASS**

```
template <typename ValueType>
class AbstractDirectLinearSolver{
protected:
    bool mFactorized;
public:
    //Constructors, destructor
    AbstractDirectLinearSolver(){
        mFactorized = false;
    }

    virtual ~AbstractDirectLinearSolver();

    //Methods
    virtual void Solve(Vector<ValueType>& x, const Vector<ValueType>& b) const = 0;
    virtual void Factorize(AbstractMatrix<ValueType>& A) = 0;
};
```

**DERIVED CLASS**

```
#include "AbstractDirectLinearSolver.hpp"

template<typename ValueType>
class CholeskySolver: public AbstractDirectLinearSolver {
private:
    AbstractMatrix<ValueType> *mR; //Pointer = Abstract class NOT ALLOWS instantiation !!
public:
    CholeskySolver() {
        mR = NULL;
    }

    ~CholeskySolver() {
        if (this->mFactorized) {  //ERROR HERE
            delete mR;
        }
    }

    void Solve(const Vector<ValueType>& x, const Vector<ValueType>& b) {
        Vector<ValueType> y(mR->ApplyLowInv(b));
        x = mR->ApplyLowerTransponse(y);
    }

    void Factorize(AbstractMatrix<ValueType>& A) {
        if (mR != NULL)
            delete mR;
        mR = NULL;
        A.CholeskyFactorization(mR);
        this->mFactorized;           //ERROR HERE
    }
};
```

Comment: Do you really get an error from both lines, or just the first one where you've forgotten the weird pseudohungarian wart (`m`) on the variable name? If so, what exactly is the error from the second one?

Comment: The first time I forgot to put the `m` before `Factorized`. After changing it eclipse's marking those lines with `Field mFactorized could not be resolved`

Comment: So this isn't a compile issue? it's an IDE issue?

Comment: Is your compiler complaining, or just Eclipse?

Comment: Well I think its an IDE issue, because I compiled it and there was no error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to inherit from a class template, rather than a class. Change the class header to:

```
template<typename ValueType>
class CholeskySolver: public AbstractDirectLinearSolver<ValueType>
                                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

It looks like the compiler bails out after complaining that `mFactorized` wasn't a member (because it didn't know about the base class), but before complaining that the base-class specifier was invalid.

If you were to comment out the problematic lines, then you'd get a slightly better (though still rather confusing) error: `expected class-name before ‘{’ token`.

Comment: Thank you so much. Yes actually I didn't think about that. Sometimes I got confused with templates.

Comment: nice catch - @BRabbit27 easy misses - I guess eclipse is quite a good IDE since it was complaining.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (this->Factorized)
```

should be

```
if (this->mFactorized)
```

The second error...

```
this->mFactorized;           //ERROR HERE
```

apart from the fact that it doesn't do anything.... I don't think there should be a problem.

Comment: Yes, the first one was a typo, but then eclipse keeps marking it as an error that says `Field Factorized could not be resolved`. I think there's no problem but why is it marked as one?

Comment: if you miss out the `this->` part is it still highlighted? Also could it need to be re-indexed. Other than that I don't know Eclipse well enough I'm afraid.